# Ubuntu 16.04 no devices shown in nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, automount

Since today all my devices stoped showing in nautilus sidebar. I still can do manual mount, but it's not very convenient.

I also reinstalled autofs with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall autofs` but it didn't work.

Also checked gnome media-handling options and are set ok with checked **automount** and **automount-open**

I tried usbmount but only works for USB devices so I rewmoved it, I can't see any device in the sidebar, internal or external, the only device shown is a manual fstab mounted internal disk.

Comment: What changed betwen yesterday and today? Did you install new software, remove existing software, edit configuration files, install a new hard drive, change user permissions, do a system  update? Knowing this can help track down where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really sorry but it seems my mistake.

I have some CIFS mounts in fstab, so if the CIFS server is down, it affects nautilus and it doesn't display local devices, even local unmounted hard drives and USB thumb drives connected after boot.

Theese are the lines of my CIFS mount in fstab

```
//localserver/storage /media/storage cifs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0

//localserver/server  /media/server  cifs x-systemd.automount,_netdev,credentials=/etc/samba/credentials,uid=martin,gid=martin,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 0 0
```

I think that **x-systemd.automount** is messing with autofs or something, preventing displaying the other connected drives if the CIFS server is down.